# How to disable Resharper on a specific solution?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am using resharper and it really saves my time except for a solution that has many projects inside. My team tfs and we develop every demand in a new branch. I want to disable resharper all branchs of this solution. Is this possible or are there any other solutions to speed up resharper?

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Options > Resharper

And click 'Suspend Now'.

---

As for speeding up your solution, Jetbrains has written a nice article on it:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html

Comment: That does not help me because i have to enable and disable manually every time. i just disabled resharper then opened new instance of visual studio and it opened disabled. i am working on many solutions but i only want to disable it on spesific solution only. Thanks for the guide. it might help me.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, there is no such feature right now

https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206618065-How-to-disable-ReSharper-for-a-specific-solution-